# .htaccess file to enable compression, send security headers, and set cache expiration

Tags: performance, security, .htaccess

This is the current `.htaccess` configuration for one of the website projects that I am working on, just as a learning exercise. This is working code and everything in it seems to be ok, My hosting company helped me set up a lot of these rules, While others where taken from various different blog posts. I'm looking to get feedback or reviews to see whether it is correct or whether it can be improved as I am still learning I don't expect it to be 100% accurate.

Some of the comments are just for my own understanding and learning purposes.
Is anything missing or incorrect? Should everything be inside an `IfModule`?

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
              SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
           # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
              BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
           # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
              BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
              BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
           # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
           # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

           # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
           # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
           # workaround to get the desired effect:

           # Don't compress images
             SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
           # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests 
        Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=122112887284; includeSubDomains; preload"
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
         IndexIgnore *.zip *.css *.php *.js *.pyt    
         Options -MultiViews -Indexes        
    
    </IfModule>

    # I'm guessing the code I added below reffers to cache storage either locally or on host/server Please check this.
    # Haven't set up any rules for Cache storage yet Add this... 
    
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
       ExpiresActive On
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"        
       ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
       ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
       ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
       ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
       ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 year"
       ExpiresByType image/ani "access plus 1 year"
       ExpiresByType image/cur "access plus 1 year"
       ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 months"
       ExpiresByType image/html "access plus 4 hours"
       ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 year"
       ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 2 months"
       ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 hours"
   </IfModule>
        # Added from :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEflwAIlLmg
        # Loading Ok with the Above code............ 
</IfModule>

    # Prevent viewing of .htaccess file Same source as above
    
    #   <Files .htaccess>                   This part is throwing a server error... 
    #       order allow, deny
    #       deny from all
    #   </Files>
```

The Above code block is my Old .htAccess file, I let my Hosting run out and they've deleted the whole entire project +2 others which was months worth of work and research.
I've now written out a new .htaccess file for which the code is included below. If anyone could review it for me & let me know if there are any mistakes, security issues, syntax errors or parts that could be optimized I would be hugely greatfull.

ServerSignature Off
DirectoryIndex coming-soon.html

```
 IndexIgnore *.bat *.css *.info *.zip *.js *.pyt *.txt *.py *.shtml   
      Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes -ExecCGI   
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml .txt .html .php .svg .shtml .py .pyt

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
       # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests 
    
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=122112887284;
         # includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    # Header expect-CT: enforce, max-age=21600
    # Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
          <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|ico|webp)$">
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
          </FilesMatch>
          <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
          </filesMatch>
                 #No access to the .htaccess und .htpasswd
          <FilesMatch "(\.htaccess|\.htpasswd)">
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
          </FilesMatch>
          <files install.php>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
          </files>            
          <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
          </filesMatch>
        
          <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private, must-revalidate"
          </filesMatch>
        
          <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
          </filesMatch>
        
          <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
          </filesMatch>
            # No access to the readme.html
          <files readme.html>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from all
            Satisfy all
          </Files>              
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
       # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
          BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
       # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
          BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
          BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
       # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
       # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

       # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
       # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
       # workaround to get the desired effect:

       # Don't compress images
         SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"        
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/ani "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/cur "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType image/html "access plus 4 hours"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 year"
   ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 2 months"
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 3 hours"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (eval\() [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:)(.*)(;) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode)(.*)(\() [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)(.*)script(.*)(>|%3) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\.\.|\.\./|~|`|<|>|\|) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|etc/passwd|self/environ) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (thumbs?(_editor|open)?|tim(thumb)?)\.php [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\'|\")(.*)(drop|insert|md5|select|union) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
    # 6G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(connect|debug|move|put|trace|track) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
   # 6G:[REFERRERS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (semalt.com|todaperfeita) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
   # 6G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)([a-z0-9]{2000,})
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(https?|ftp|php):/
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(base64_encode)(.*)(\()
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(=\\\'|=\\%27|/\\\'/?)\.
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(\$(\&)?|\*|\"|\.|,|&|&amp;?)/?$
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\\\"\\\")
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(~|`|<|>|:|;|,|%|\\|\{|\}|\[|\]|\|)
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(=|\$&|_mm|cgi-|muieblack)
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(&pws=0|_vti_|\(null\)|\{\$itemURL\}|echo(.*)kae|etc/passwd|eval\(|self/environ)
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)\.(aspx?|bash|bak?|cfg|cgi|dll|exe|git|hg|ini|jsp|log|mdb|out|sql|svn|swp|tar|rar|rdf)$
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(^$|(wp-)?config|mobiquo|phpinfo|shell|sqlpatch|thumb|thumb_editor|thumbopen|timthumb|webshell)\.php
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>    
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /coming-soon.html [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>     
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      # SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>    
      # MIME Types         ...>[Some of these are redundant & will never be used in My Application Only include the ones you wish to use.]
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # ::>>. Text/Plain Text
      AddType text/plain .txt
      AddType text/xml .xml
      AddType text/xsl .xsl
      AddType text/xsd .xsd
      AddType text/css .css
      AddType text/x-js .js4
      AddType text/javascript .js3
      AddType text/x-component .htc
      AddType text/html .html .shtml .htm
      AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    # ::>>. Images
      AddType image/png .png
      AddType image/bmp .bmp
      AddType image/gif .gif
      AddType image/x-icon .ico
      AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
      AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
      AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    # ::>>. Audio
      AddType audio/wav .wav
      AddType audio/wma .wma
      AddType video/avi .avi
      AddType audio/ogg .ogg
      AddType video/divx .divx
      AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
      AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
      AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
      AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
    # ::>>. Video
      AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
      AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
      AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    # ::>>. Applications
      AddType application/zip .zip
      AddType application/pdf .pdf
      AddType application/x-tar .tar
      AddType application/json .json
      AddType application/java .class
      AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
      AddType application/font-woff .woff
      AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
      AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
      AddType application/x-javascript .js
      AddType application/javascript .js2
      AddType application/msword .doc .docx
      AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
      AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
      AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
      AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
      AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype .otf
      AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
      AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
      AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype .ttf .ttc
      AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
      AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
      AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
      AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
      AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
      AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
      AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
      AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
      AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
</IfModule>
```

the backticks in the `RewriteCond` match seem to be messing up the syntax highlighting on Code review, but there's not much I can do about that.